# Laravel 5 duplicate folder structure

Tags: php, laravel-5, directory

I have setup new Laravel project and things went smooth. No errors at all, but my folder paths to images, CSS and JS files are messed up. Like this:

```
http://localhost/project/public/project/public/themes/default/assets/img/logo.png
```

It seems there is a duplication of project/public directory. There are no errors at all just messed up structure. I am using XAMPP on Windows 10 if this helps at all. On windows 7 on my laptop I had no issues of this kind with the same App.

Apache config should be set accordingly since other local apps work fine.